# ¿Que formas correctas hay de abrir un nuevo formulario de windows? C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

No he encontrado información acerca de varias formas de abrir un formulario de **Windows Forms** desde otro formulario en **C#**, con el ejemplo que pongo abajo.

Supongo que hay muchas maneras, pero seguro que alguién pone alguna que no conozca.

Yo en mi caso utilizo esta manera:

```
new Thread(() => new Formulario().Show()).Start();
```

El ejemplo de uso que uso en este caso sería, que desde un formulario de login, si aciertas la clave, abra otro formulario desde el formulario de login, con tus datos de usuario y cierre el formulario de login, eso sí, al cerrar el formulario de login, que no cierre el formulario con datos de usuario.

¡Gracias! Soy nuevo usuario activo en la comunidad, espero vuestras respuestas.

Comment: Por que utilizas un nuevo thread para mostrar un nuevo formulario? De todas maneras, tu pregunta en su formato actual podría quedar cerrada dado que puede ser _basada en opiniones_. No creo que exista una forma mas _correcta_ de abrir un formulario. La forma es crear la instancia y llamar a `Show` o `ShowDialog`.

Comment: En mi caso, para que al finalizar el formulario de login, no se me cierre el formulario con los datos del usuario, No sé si hay alguna manera más correcta de hacerlo.

La idea del ejemplo es desde login hacer lo siguiente:

`private void botonlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
new Thread(() => new Formulario().Show()).Start(); 
this.Close();
}`

Comment: lo mas usual es Form1 frm = new Form1(); frm.Show();//frm.ShowDialog();//ocultas el formulario this.Hide();